# Hue internal architecture and hive query execution

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

How does cloudera hue executes hive query as a particular user with SSO implemented. Is there any documentation available for that?

Answer (score 1):

Hue is a Python web application (Django, I believe) and uses a Python Hive client that [forwards through the signed in username to Hive `user.name` impersonation support](http://gethue.com/ldap-or-pam-pass-through-authentication-with-hive-or-impala/)

There's a docs folder on Github - https://github.com/cloudera/hue/tree/master/docs